# Copy text from listview to clipboard on long press

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I am making an app that will copy the text on list view after long press. I created an array of string in the listview now I want to implement long press event in fragment. Like when I long press the list Item 1 it should be copied in to the clipboard. How can I implement it?

**OneFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.dragedy.kickasshumor.R;


public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

}
```

**FragmentOne.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/list"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Strings.xml**

```
<resources>
   <string-array name="list">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <item>Item 2</item>
        <item>Item 3</item>
        <item>Item 4</item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
    ClipData myClip;
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)
        getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
            String text = "hello world";
            myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ClipboardManager you can copy text from listview row

```
  @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);
            listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    return false;
                   // this is textview which you used in listview row 
                    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
                    ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    cm.setText(textView.getText().toString());
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: cm.setText() is deprecated. @febi-mathew's answer is the recommended approach.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can do it

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        // after populating listview here and setting adapter etc.

        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
                // your method here
                return true;
            }
        }); 

        return view;
    }
```